# Jumping to the next available date when merging panels

Tags: r, date, merge, panel

I asked a very similar question just before. The difference is, before it was a situation with only one company. Now it's a panel data structure. 
I want to merge two data.frames by date. Data contains stock data for each trading day of a stock. Events contains news about the company. Some news were published on non-trading days, so there are no stock data for this day. For example on 04.01.2000 some news for company "A" were published. I want to merge this article with the return of the NEXT trading day, in this case the return on the 06.01.2000. So how can I jump to the next trading day when merging in a panel situation?

```
date1 <- c("01.01.2000","02.01.2000","03.01.2000","06.01.2000","07.01.2000","09.01.2000","01.01.2000","02.01.2000","03.01.2000","06.01.2000","07.01.2000","09.01.2000")
ret1 <- c(-2.0,1.1,3,1.4,-0.2, 0.6, 0.1, -0.21, -1.2, 0.9, 0.3, -0.1)
company1 <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B")
df <- data.frame(date1, ret1, company1)
df

#         date1  ret1 company1
# 1  01.01.2000 -2.00        A
# 2  02.01.2000  1.10        A
# 3  03.01.2000  3.00        A
# 4  06.01.2000  1.40        A
# 5  07.01.2000 -0.20        A
# 6  09.01.2000  0.60        A
# 7  01.01.2000  0.10        B
# 8  02.01.2000 -0.21        B
# 9  03.01.2000 -1.20        B
# 10 06.01.2000  0.90        B
# 11 07.01.2000  0.30        B
# 12 09.01.2000 -0.10        B

date2 <- c("02.01.2000","03.01.2000","04.01.2000","08.01.2000","05.01.2000","08.01.2000","09.01.2000")
news2 <- c("blabla11", "blabla12","blabla13","blabla14","blabla21","blabla22","blabla23")
company2 <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B")

event <- data.frame(date2, news2, company2)
event 

#        date2    news2 company2
# 1 02.01.2000 blabla11        A
# 2 03.01.2000 blabla12        A
# 3 04.01.2000 blabla13        A
# 4 08.01.2000 blabla14        A
# 5 05.01.2000 blabla21        B
# 6 08.01.2000 blabla22        B
# 7 09.01.2000 blabla23        B
```

the output should look like this:

```
#        date2    news2 company2 date1        ret
# 1 02.01.2000 blabla11        A 02.01.2000  1.10
# 2 03.01.2000 blabla12        A 03.01.2000  3.00
# 3 04.01.2000 blabla13        A 06.01.2000  1.40
# 4 08.01.2000 blabla14        A 09.01.2000  0.60
# 5 05.01.2000 blabla21        B 06.01.2000  0.90
# 6 08.01.2000 blabla22        B 09.01.2000 -0.10
# 7 09.01.2000 blabla23        B 09.01.2000 -0.10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more or less the same as your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23307653/jumping-to-the-next-available-date-when-merging-data-frames-by-date). The only change is that you'll have to set "company,date" as the key columns to perform the join on (note that the order is important - it'll first sort by company and then by date).

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.2
setDT(df)
setDT(event)
setkey(df, company1, date1)
setkey(event, company2, date2)
df[, date := date1]
df[event, roll=-Inf]

   company1      date1 ret1       date    news2
1:        A 02.01.2000  1.1 02.01.2000 blabla11
2:        A 03.01.2000  3.0 03.01.2000 blabla12
3:        A 04.01.2000  1.4 06.01.2000 blabla13
4:        A 08.01.2000  0.6 09.01.2000 blabla14
5:        B 05.01.2000  0.9 06.01.2000 blabla21
6:        B 08.01.2000 -0.1 09.01.2000 blabla22
7:        B 09.01.2000 -0.1 09.01.2000 blabla23
```

Comment: @ Arun: thank you so much! I would be lost without people like you!